# where does df.cache() is stored

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I would like to understand in which node (driver or worker/executor) does below code is stored

```
df.cache() //df is a large dataframe (200GB)
```

And which has a better performance: using sql `cachetable` or `cache()`. My understanding is that one of them is lazy and the other is eager.

Answer (score 10):

`df.cache()` calls the `persist()` method which stores on storage level as `MEMORY_AND_DISK`, but you can change the storage level

The `persist()` method calls 
    sparkSession.sharedState.cacheManager.cacheQuery()
and when you see the code for `cacheTable` it also calls the same 
    sparkSession.sharedState.cacheManager.cacheQuery()

that means both are same and are **lazily evaluated** (only evaluated once action is performed), except `persist` method can store as the storage level provided, these are the available storage level

- NONE
- DISK_ONLY
- DISK_ONLY_2
- MEMORY_ONLY
- MEMORY_ONLY_2
- MEMORY_ONLY_SER
- MEMORY_ONLY_SER_2
- MEMORY_AND_DISK
- MEMORY_AND_DISK_2
- MEMORY_AND_DISK_SER
- MEMORY_AND_DISK_SER_2
- OFF_HEAP

You can also use the SQL `CACHE TABLE` which is not lazily evaluated and stores the whole table in memory, which may also lead to `OOM`

**Summary:** `cache()`, `persist()`, `cacheTable()` are lazily evaluated and need to perform an action to work where as `SQL CACHE TABLE` is an eager

See here for [details](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset@persist():Dataset.this.type)!

You can choose as per your requirement!

Hope this helps!

Comment: Slighty incorrect because for dataframes `cache` and default `persist` is `MEMORY_AND_DISK`

Comment: @Shankar Koirala :my question is more towards where the data is stored when I say df.cache() or persist()? When I say where is it in memory on a single worker node or driver node or distributed across nodes  etc.. I do understand there are multiple storage levels

Comment: @philantrovert :can you please provide me the source documentation where it says by default persist() is MEMORY_AND_DISK and one more question in this case what happens when cluster goes down or application restarted will the data in disk will be erased?

Comment: There you go : https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/Dataset.scala#L2714

And if the cluster goes down, you lose track of the data too.

Answer (score 4):

Just adding my 25 cents. 
A SparkDF.cache() would load the data in executor memory. 
It will not load in driver memory. Which is what's desired.
Here's a snapshot of 50% of data load post a df.cache().count() I just ran.

[image]

Cache() persists in memory and disk as delineated by *koiralo*, and is also lazy evaluated.

Cachedtable() stores on disk and is resilient to node failures for this reason.

Credit: https://forums.databricks.com/answers/63/view.html

Answer (score 1):

The `cache` (or `persist`) method marks the DataFrame for caching in memory (or disk, if necessary, as the other answer says), but this happens only once an action is performed on the DataFrame, and only in a lazy fashion, i.e., if you ultimately read only 100 rows, only those 100 rows are cached.  Creating a temporary table and using `cacheTable` is eager in the sense that it will cache the entire table immediately.  Which is more performant depends on your situation.  One thing that I've done with ordinary DataFrame `cache` is to immediately call `.count()` right after, forcing the DataFrame to be cached, and obviating the need to register a temp table and such.

Answer (score 1):

> **Spark Memory**. this is the memory pool managed by Apache Spark. Its size can be calculated as `(“Java Heap” – “Reserved Memory”) * spark.memory.fraction, and with Spark 1.6.0 defaults it gives us (“Java Heap” – 300MB) * 0.75.` For example, with 4GB heap this pool would be 2847MB in size. This whole pool is split into 2 regions – Storage Memory and Execution Memory, and the boundary between them is set by spark.memory.storageFraction parameter, which defaults to 0.5. The advantage of this new memory management scheme is that this boundary is not static, and in case of memory pressure the boundary would be moved, i.e. one region would grow by borrowing space from another one. I would discuss the “moving” this boundary a bit later, now let’s focus on how this memory is being used:
>   
>   **`1. Storage Memory.`** This pool is used for both storing Apache Spark cached data and for temporary space serialized data “unroll”. Also all the “broadcast” variables are stored there as cached blocks. In case you’re curious, here’s the code of unroll. As you may see, it does not require that enough memory for unrolled block to be available – in case there is not enough memory to fit the whole unrolled partition it would directly put it to the drive if desired persistence level allows this. As of “broadcast”, all the broadcast variables are stored in cache with MEMORY_AND_DISK persistence level.
>   
>   **`2. Execution Memory.`** This pool is used for storing the objects required during the execution of Spark tasks. For example, it is used to store shuffle intermediate buffer on the Map side in memory, also it is used to store hash table for hash aggregation step. This pool also supports spilling on disk if not enough memory is available, but the blocks from this pool cannot be forcefully evicted by other threads (tasks).
>   Ok, so now let’s focus on the moving boundary between Storage Memory and Execution Memory. Due to nature of Execution Memory, you cannot forcefully evict blocks from this pool, because this is the data used in intermediate computations and the process requiring this memory would simply fail if the block it refers to won’t be found. But it is not so for the Storage Memory – it is just a cache of blocks stored in RAM, and if we evict the block from there we can just update the block metadata reflecting the fact this block was evicted to HDD (or simply removed), and trying to access this block Spark would read it from HDD (or recalculate in case your persistence level does not allow to spill on HDD).
>   
>   So, we can forcefully evict the block from Storage Memory, but cannot do so from Execution Memory. When Execution Memory pool can borrow some space from Storage Memory? It happens when either:
>   
>   There is free space available in Storage Memory pool, i.e. cached blocks don’t use all the memory available there. Then it just reduces the Storage Memory pool size, increasing the Execution Memory pool.
>   Storage Memory pool size exceeds the initial Storage Memory region size and it has all this space utilized. This situation causes forceful eviction of the blocks from Storage Memory pool, unless it reaches its initial size.
>   In turn, Storage Memory pool can borrow some space from Execution Memory pool only if there is some free space in Execution Memory pool available.
>   
>   Initial Storage Memory region size, as you might remember, is calculated as “Spark Memory” * spark.memory.storageFraction = (“Java Heap” – “Reserved Memory”) * spark.memory.fraction * spark.memory.storageFraction. With default values, this is equal to `(“Java Heap” – 300MB) * 0.75 * 0.5 = (“Java Heap” – 300MB) * 0.375. For 4GB heap this would result in 1423.5MB of RAM in initial Storage Memory region`.

reference -https://0x0fff.com/spark-memory-management/

Comment: Hi Kishore, Thanks for the explanation. I have one basic question. where the broadcast variable stores in worker node. I believe cache will store in spark.memory.storageFraction portion. Thanks in advance...